# SetSuspendState in Windows 8 Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to somehow suspend the computer from Windows 8 store app? In Windows Forms I could use Application.SetSuspendState, or call SetSuspendState through P/Invoke from powrprof.dll, but nothing seems to work here. I suspect that in fact the apps aren't allowed to suspend the computer, but I'd like to be certain of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx) and [Native API's supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205762.aspx) in Windows Store Apps, the answer is **No**. The lists do not contain reference to those API's, thus you are not to use them if they are to be accepted.